# Is it one word or two? how do you formulate questions with Or (is question word required?)

Tags: questions, wh-questions, questions-v-relatives

I am not sure about the grammar rules of formulating questions. It is very tricky with so many ways to ask questions. I learned that YES/NO questions do not need question words.

Now I tried to formulate a question using the "OR" to question about two choices but could only think of a question without a question word. I tried to use question words but failed to come out with a clear question.

Below is an example of the type of question using OR.

> Is it one word or two?

Comment: Question words really only show up with 'and' I think, like "when and where did you see the criminal", they don't show up with 'or'.

Comment: I've written an answer, but I think you are doing something wrong.  Why do you want to form a sentence with a question word and "or".  What is the problem of communication that you are facing?  Is the proper answer simply "Don't do that".

Answer (score 1):

In your example the two alternatives are presented as the complement in a Verb subject-complement question

> (Is) - (it) - (one word or two)?

When you has a question with a question word like "what" or "who" The question word comes to the front to get a Complement-verb-subject word order

> (What) (is) (it)?

The complement can have two parts joined with "or". So with question words you get something like

> What or who is it?

Comment: I do translation from my native "Arabic" language to English. I struggled to formulate a question using two options. Normally when I use "which" to ask for a choice (i.e which one do you like). Nonetheless, I want to give the audience a question that asks them to pick between two options like the said example: is it number one or two?. 

I want to understand how to use questions with Or. How many ways are there to use "Or" in questions, for instance?

Answer (score 0):

- Is it one word or two? [two words, implied]
- Is it one or two words? [one word implied]
- Is it one word or two words? [most formal, writing]

A question with the verb **be** does **not** use a question word.

However, there are yes/no questions that begin with an auxiliary verb without a be verb:

**Does** he speak Chinese? [Yes, No]